# mysql query referring three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables which are destination,location and intention.
They are having the following relationship with eachother. I am trying to fetch the locations and their corresponding destinations for given intention. 
But im currently failing to do this.
Any ideas?

[database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4E7oq.jpg)

Ex: Get the location names and their corresponding destination on 'hiking' intention

Failed query :

```
select destination.name,location.name from location,destination,intention where
intention.name='hiking' AND location.destination_id=destination.destination_id AND
intention.intention_id=location.intention_id
```

[Example location data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78uEr.jpg)

[Example destination data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8mqQ.jpg)

[Example intention data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQLnX.jpg)

Comment: Your query syntax, while not ideal, actually looks like it should work.  What is your current output?

Comment: i am getting an empty response. There are records that  satisfy this condition  though.

Comment: Use explicit left joins everywhere.

Comment: Can you demonstrate an example for this.

Comment: To make your question complete, can you include some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intention_id of 1 for hiking does not exist in the location table, thus no rows returned